# Which SSL Certificate is approved by Android?

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have developed an app  with phonegap, and it uses ssl in all the ajax calls. It works fine, but when I signed the app, these calls stop working and I think it is because of the SSL certificate is not valid for Android.

- How can I settle the problem ?
- Do I need to buy other SSL certificate recognised by Android ?

Answer (score 0):

SSL Ceritficates are used by browsers to confirm a sites legitimacy, this is done by the help of a 3rd party usually called a CA(Certificate Authority).

If you are getting a SSL certificate handshake exception it is most probably because the website your are trying to connect has a self signed certificate.

**Solution :**
Add the sites certificate to your Trust store and use it for further network requests.
Head over to the   [official developers website](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html) to know how to add the certificate to the key store.
To actually get the certificate, use Openssl to get the certificate chain.
    `openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443 -prexit`

the certificate you require will mostly be the root certificate in the chain.

Comment: if I try to run penssl s_client www.mydomain.com:443 -prexit I get: unknown option www.mydomain.com:443

Comment: @FerminGarcia Sorry about that, missed the -connect flag. 
I have updated the the answer with the correct one.